# How to replace spaces in "§ 1", "§s 1, 2, [indeterminate number]" all with underscores in regex?

Tags: regex, replace, paragraph

I have a simple regex pattern that replaces a space between paragraph sign and a number with an underscore:
Find: § (\d+)
Replace: §_$1

It works fine and turns "§ 5" into "§_5", but here are cases when there are more numbers following the paragraphs sign, so how to turn "§s 23, 12" also  into "§s_1,_2_and_3"? Is it possible with regex?

I have tried modifying the original regex pattern, (§|§-d) (\d+) finds only some of the cases, and I have no idea how to write the replacement.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'§\w*\s+\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*', lambda x: re.sub(r'\s+', '_', x.group()), text)
```

The `re.sub(r'\s+', '_', x.group()` replaces chunks of one or more whitespaces with a single `_` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uOJ1TN/1), details:

- `§` - a `§` char
- `\w*` - zero or more word chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:,\s*\d+)*` - zero or more sequences of a comma, zero or more whitespaces and one or more digits.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kfUuz8):

```py
import re
text = "§s 23, 12"
print(re.sub(r'§\w*\s+\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*', lambda x: re.sub(r'\s+', '_', x.group()), text))
# => §s_23,_12
```